# gerrit ssh permission denied (public key)

Tags: ssh, gerrit, permission-denied

I am struggling to authenticate with **gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz** using ssh.

I am trying to use **ssh** on **windows**.

My **.ssh\config** looks like this:

```
Host openbmc.gerrit
        Hostname gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz
        Port 29418
        User patelutpal
```

The contents of my **.ssh** directory look like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 utpalp 1049089  107 Dec  7 23:04 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 utpalp 1049089  411 Dec  7 21:10 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r-- 1 utpalp 1049089   97 Dec  7 21:10 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 utpalp 1049089 3381 Dec  7 22:14 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 utpalp 1049089  741 Dec  7 22:14 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 utpalp 1049089  419 Dec  7 22:53 known_hosts
```

I have logged into **gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz** with my **github** account with id **patelutpal**.

I have added **id_rsa.pub** ssh key to my settings in **https://gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz/settings/#SSHKeys**

When I try:

```
C:\Users\utpalp\git>ssh -p 29418 -vvvt patelutpal@gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz
```

I get the following output.

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/config
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz" port 29418
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz [169.44.58.24] port 29418.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version GerritCodeReview_3.2.6 (APACHE-SSHD-2.4.0)
debug1: no match: GerritCodeReview_3.2.6 (APACHE-SSHD-2.4.0)
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz:29418 as 'patelutpal'
debug3: put_host_port: [gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz]:29418
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz]:29418
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group17-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group15-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:LCaJB3JewPu5SBvlqsZfvKJD7yOVi7YaLWAEjsHSG60
debug3: put_host_port: [169.44.58.24]:29418
debug3: put_host_port: [gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz]:29418
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz]:29418
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [169.44.58.24]:29418
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/utpalp/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host '[gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz]:29418' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:obA7xm+M+BuNoN/miSnhiIZmPbCIdpvMTj+xu8SRDsI
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:zOx6/ktAHFTrf/yC4zBC55mEbfRZHF290Q29st34SA0
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:obA7xm+M+BuNoN/miSnhiIZmPbCIdpvMTj+xu8SRDsI
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:zOx6/ktAHFTrf/yC4zBC55mEbfRZHF290Q29st34SA0
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\utpalp/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
patelutpal@gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I dont know what to do. I think I have done all the right things. I wonder if this is a server side error. Can someone please help?

I will gladly provide more information if needed.

Thank you.
-Utpal

Answer (score 18):

**Context**

[OpenSSH 8.8](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8) disables RSA signatures using the SHA-1 hash algorithm because they are [considered cryptographically broken](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8).
[Git for Windows 2.33.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.33.1.windows.1) upgrades OpenSSH to 8.8.

Note that this is a client side restriction.

**Error**

When trying to use a newer SSH client with git to clone or fetch using SSH, the following error might be observed:

```
git fetch
Fetching origin
dxxxxx@your.gerrit.host: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
error: Could not fetch origin
Done
```

**Solution**

You must provide a key type that is accepted by OpenSSH 8.8. OpenSSH [recommends](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8) e.g. Ed25519:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

copy content of ".ssh/id_ed25519.pub" to your Gerrit user settings

If your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file sets the IdentityFile option, then you may need to change the path accordingly, e.g.:

```
Host your.gerrit.host
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Alternatively you can configure the client to accept RSA by adding this ssh config option in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been after this issue the whole day and I couldn't find out what I was doing wrong. For reference: my WSL instance had an old SSH/OpenSSL. So I downloaded both and built from source. After installing them, I continued getting that my public key wasn't accepted by gerrit. I thought that I had linked or installed ssh wrong and that it wasn't using the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key. But after using the ed25519 keygen, and adding it to gerrit, everything worked instantaneously. Once again: I am using WSL Ubuntu, not Windows directly, for future reference

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue recently on Windows and GitBash. I downgraded to GitBash 2.27 and it worked again.

Comment: I don't think that suggesting a person downgrade a program or library is the correct advice. If something has changed, then we must know why and what the new method of operation is (like the other answer explains)